# Exception at Exporting EventLog

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

I use the fallowing code to export a Windows-Event-Log:

```
var els = new EventLogSession();
els.ExportLogAndMessages("Application", 
                            PathType.LogName, 
                            "*[System[Provider[@Name='Prayon.Client']]]", 
                            tempEventLogPath, 
                            false, 
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

This is generally working. But on one machine, I get the fallowing Exception:

```
System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException: Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig
bei System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException.Throw(Int32 errorCode)
bei System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.NativeWrapper.EvtArchiveExportedLog(EventLogHandle session, String logFilePath, Int32 locale, Int32 flags)
bei System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession.ExportLogAndMessages(String path, PathType pathType, String query, String targetFilePath, Boolean tolerateQueryErrors, CultureInfo targetCultureInfo)
```

`"Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig"` means on english: `"The pathname is invalid"`

The Application-EventLog is existing and `tempEventLogPath` is also valid.

Does someone know, what there can be wrong?

Comment: What's the value of tempEventLogPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the directory LocalMetaData in the target directory.

I had the same problem.
The first call works, but every following call gets the above mentioned exception.
Investigation with Processmonitor showd me that additional to the evtx file the directory LocalMetaData is accessesd. 
After deleting this directory the export works again.

Answer (score 0):

See the possible answer in:
[EvtArchiveExportedLog fails with ERROR_DIRECTORY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301271/evtarchiveexportedlog-fails-with-error-directory)

The thing is, even if you have access to the directory which is mentioned in the answer, you can fail due to UAC notifications (you can disable UAC and it should work).